# is there a .NET function to parse/convert a string into an optional value?

Tags: .net, parsing, f#, option-type

"string" converts an optional value to a string. But, is there a .NET function to convert such a string back to the optional value?

```
let x = Some 3.0
let y = string x   // y = "Some(3)"
let z = ?<float> x // z = Some 3.0
```

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin i'm saving an optional value to a file so that it can be read again the next time my program starts. the fact that the "string" function converts one way suggested to me that there is probably a function goes the other way. i prefer not reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a built-in one. But you can write a function that does this for quite a few types. Any type that has a static member `TryParse : string * byref<T> -> bool` works with the following, which includes all number types, `bool`, `DateTime` and a few more:

```
let inline tryParse< ^T when ^T : (static member TryParse : string * byref< ^T> -> bool)> (s: string) =
    let mutable res = Unchecked.defaultof< ^T>
    if (^T : (static member TryParse : string * byref< ^T> -> bool)(s, &res)) then
        Some res
    else
        None

tryParse<float> "3.45" // => Some 3.45
tryParse<float> "test" // ==> None
```

Comment: not quite sure how it works exactly but interesting answer. i would expect "test" to throw an exception though